# Canvas images and Click event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events

I have currently two circles in a `<canvas>` tag with HTML5 & JavaScript.

Now I'm trying to add an image (done) that changes based on mouse-over and click.

It's basically an implementation of a play / pause button with an extra color change when the user mouse-overs the button.

I can't seem to figure out how events work on shapes in HTML5 since they are not objects ... Here is my code at the moment :

```
window.onload = function() {

      var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
      var centerY = canvas.height / 2;


      //Outer circle
      context.beginPath();  
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      context.fillStyle = "#000";
      context.fill();
      context.stroke();

      //Inner cicle
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, 75, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      context.fillStyle = "#fff";
      context.fill();
      context.stroke();

      //Play / Pause button
      var imagePlay = new Image();
      var imageHeight = 48/2;
      imagePlay.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imagePlay, centerX - imageHeight, centerY - imageHeight);
      };
      imagePlay.src = "images/play.gif";

}
```

1. How to handle events on shapes created with `<canvas>`?
2. How to clean-up / remove images on the `<canvas>` when replacing it with another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is technically no way to register mouse events on canvas-drawn shapes. However, if you use a library, like Raphael (http://raphaeljs.com/), it can keep track of shape positions and thus figure out what shape is receiving the mouse event. here's an example:

```
var circle = r.circle(50, 50, 40);

circle.attr({fill: "red"});

circle.mouseover(function (event) {
    this.attr({fill: "red"});
});
```

As you can see, it's very simple this way. For modifying shapes, this library will also come in handy. Without it you would need to remember how to redraw everything each time you make a change

Comment: Oh ok, thanks ! Do I HAVE to use a library ? I'm rewriting an app so that it uses less JavaScript files and other improvements to make it lighter. So I'm a bit reluctant to use another library ... but if I have to ... Again thank you for your quick answer !

Comment: I would suggest a library, but I have done without one before. You'll need to keep track of all of your shapes and their position, then use math to figure out if a coordinate falls within it.

Answer (score 1):

Well The simple answer is you can't.  You either will have to find the coordinates of the click event and calculate whether you want to perform an option or not or you can use area and map tags and overlay the canvas element with it.  To change a canvas use the clearRect function to draw paint a rectangle over everything and then redraw what you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no "built-in" way of keeping track of shapes drawn on the canvas. They are not treated as objects, but rather just pixels in an area. If you want to handle events on shapes drawn on the canvas, you would need to keep track of the area each shape covers, and then determine which shape you're triggering the event for based on the mouse position.
2. You can just draw over other shapes if you want to replace it with something. You might want to take a look at [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html).

If you want to treat your drawings as objects, I would recommend using [SVG](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp) instead of canvas.

Another option is to use [buttons](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp), and then style them using CSS.

Basically, what you're doing now really wasn't the intended purpose or use of the canvas. It's like using a pencil to hammer in nails - you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Thank for your answer too ! I actually considered using SVG because of the anti-aliasing problems in <canvas> but it seems to be less compatible then <canvas> in older browsers and it seems to be much slower. Don't know, I could be wrong though.

Comment: Canvas is one of the new elements introduced as part of HTML5. SVG is an earlier standard that came before canvas, so I believe it should actually be more compatible with older browsers. The main benefit of SVG to you is that you can attach event handlers to the objects. This [link] has a brief comparison that you may find helpful.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the link in my last comment. [Here it is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element#Canvas_versus_Scalable_Vector_Graphics_.28SVG.29). :)

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that you cannot create click events for objects drawn on the canvas there is a workaround: Wrap the canvas in a DIV tag and then add the images within the DIV tag above the CANVAS tag.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="img1.jpg" id="img1"></img>
    <canvas id="thecanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Then use CSS to make the images position:absolute and use left:*px and top:*px attributes to place the image over the canvas where you would have normally drawn it.

```
#img1{
position:absolute;
left: 10px;
top: 10px;
 }
```

You can then add click events to the image which is placed over the canvas giving the impression that you are clicking on the canvas(the below example uses the jQuery click() function)

```
$( "#img1" ).click(function(){
    alert("Thanks for clicking me");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a ray into the canvas and manually test your images for intersection with the ray. You should look at it like you press, and send a ray into the screen. You should write a

```
objectsUnderPoint( x, y );
```

function that returns an array of all the images that intersect with the ray at x, y.

This is the only real right answer, and this is how it is usually done in 3D engines as well.