# Custom shape (spiral) animated buttons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, button, shapes

How to go about generating buttons of a custom shape?

Specifically I'm trying to generate something similar to this spiral:

[image]

*(For the curious, this represents the 88 keys on the piano).*

I'm thinking I could mathematically create a set of "perimeter path" points for each button -- that would be easy enough.

What I'm not sure is whether I can create some SVG polygon that is click-able, or whether I need to mathematically process a click to figure out which button it landed closest to.

The buttons will be coloured.  When a button is pressed I need it to appear bigger and brighter, then gradually shrink back to its original size and colour.

EDIT: as always I will upload my findings and eventually tidy it up and break it into an answer.

[Add onclick and onmouseover to canvas element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628184/add-onclick-and-onmouseover-to-canvas-element)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes
http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2012/october/new-html5-canvas-features.html
http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2014/march/an-example-of-html5-canvas-path2d-objects.html
-> https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/01/canvas-2d-new-docs-path2d-hit-regions/
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/raphael/intro/

The above links seem to show that HTML Canvas provides isPointInPath()

Comment: Are you looking to use an HTML5 canvas to draw this?

Comment: SVG may also be a good approach, you can attach click events to it..

Comment: @jwatts1980 I think so...?  I definitely don't want to constrain myself to supporting every old browser...

Comment: I don't know of a way to get these complex shapes any other way than to use 2D animation techniques on an HTML5 canvas. But I have not worked with SVG.